# tablesorter works on all except one

Tags: jquery

I have a tablesorter that works on all except one column.
See http://www.dbno.us/finance/beta/old.php?index=sp100

When you click on P/E, it sorts incorrectly. On ascending order, it will put 223.68 ahead of 23.30. On descending order, it will put 9.22 ahead of 86.85.

Comment: i think you should refer the documentation,where you will find some option to sort your column based on different data type.

Answer (score 0):

P/E is being sorted alphabetically rather than numerically, the presence of "N/A" values is probably making tablesorter think that the column contains strings rather than numbers.

You want to use `$.tablesorter.addParser()` to add a custom parser for that column and then something like this to bind the parser to that column:

```
$("#stocktable").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[4,0],[6,1]],
    headers:  { 4: { sorter: 'yourCustomParser' } }
});
```

Where `yourCustomParser` is the parser you set up with `.addParser()`. Your custom parser will need to convert "N/A" to something numeric for the comparison. The tablesorter documentation has examples of custom parsers.